# MySql insert with multiple values in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I wonder if there are any advantage or disadvantage using multiples values in a single query, or whether is better to insert those values into a separate queries?

For example, supposed that I have the table `tester_tbl` which has 2 columns of type int both, `id1` and `id2` respectively and I want insert the values `2, 3, 4` to the column `id2` and the value `1` to the column `id1`, something like this :

```
+-----+-----+
| id1 | id2 |
+-----+-----+
|   1 |   2 |
|   1 |   3 |
|   1 |   4 |
+-----+-----+
```

To accomplish it, what do you recommends me?, use a single query that inserted those values, so `INSERT INTO tester_tbl (id1, id2) VALUES (1, 2), (1,3), (1,4);`, or do multiples queries to insert those values, so

```
`INSERT INTO tester_tbl (id1, id2) VALUES (1, 2);`,
`INSERT INTO tester_tbl (id1, id2) VALUES (1, 3);`,
`INSERT INTO tester_tbl (id1, id2) VALUES (1, 4);`
```

If anyone can tell me a better way to do this, I'd be grateful.

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html), MySQL inserts with multiple values in one query is more efficient and faster.

Answer (score 1):

The first way is better.  More efficient and faster, especially with many inserts.  A lot faster.  I speak from experience.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Uncle Iroh, I'm grateful about you.

Answer (score 0):

In my mind the only reason you might want to use separate queries, is if you needed to enforce transactional integrity on each one individually.  Outside of having that need, use a single query.